# Issue with slideshow not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having issues getting the slideshow within my html document to work properly. I am trying to place the slideshow within my homebody div so that the layout is the same as the rest of my webpages. Also my prev and next buttons do not appear beside the image where I would like them. Attached is a link to my code sample for the slide show and for the homebody container div. Any help would be appreciated.

`enter code here`
    https://jsfiddle.net/deandretodd/km5npyrr/#&togetherjs=LvuLT6Uvf9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'homebody'.

- In your fiddle, the images are linked to local images so they don't work - updated those.
- I moved your JS to the HTML code window because jsfiddle doesn't recognize them if they're in the JS window for some reason.
- I removed the float from the slideshow container (`.slideshow-container`) and applied `margin: auto;` so it would center
- Your back/next links had `top: 50%; margin-top: 50%;` pushing them way too far down the screen. Applied `position: relative` to the slideshow container (`.slideshow-container`) to make that the relative parent for the back/next arrows to position themselves, removed the `margin-top` CSS and applied `transform: translateY(-50%);` to them so they are centered vertically in the slideshow.

Is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/km5npyrr/2/

```css
.slideshow-container {
  width: 650px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6 ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.dots {
  clear: both;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

body p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="text">Caption</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center" class="dots">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Coker that helped out a lot.The homebody was a div that is part of the layout of the page. I wanted all of the webpages to have the same layout so I wanted to place the slideshow within the <div class="homebody">. Can I just place the same css that I have for the homebody to the slideshow container to get it to align on the page how I want it?

Comment: @DeAndre re: "Can I just place the same css that I have for the homebody to the slideshow container to get it to align on the page how I want it?" maybe. Have you tried it to see? Worst case it doesn't work. Just back up your files first.

Comment: Feel free to share your site or the code or whatever and I might be able to help.

Comment: Ok I definitely will. I'll share it tomorrow! Thanks for the help!